# How to set up Docker file to install Calabash-android?

Tags: docker, calabash, calabash-android

I am setting up Calabash-android inside a docker container. Could not find a proper method to edit the existing file. Can I simply use the command  `gem install calabash-android` along with the other commands in the docket file? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: try those docker containers https://github.com/neofreko/calabash-android-cloud9 and https://github.com/neofreko/calabash-android-cloud9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. But at first you need base image with ruby. You can choose it in `https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/` page. This is example config:

```
FROM ruby:2.1-onbuild
RUN gem install calabash-android
```

Or you can just install Ruby in simple ubuntu based image:

```
FROM fcat/ubuntu-universe:12.04
RUN apt-get -qy install ruby1.9.1
RUN gem install calabash-android
```

Comment: I have tried to manually install it. But it says as if it required ruby version higher than or equals to 2.0. But could n't install it.

Comment: Show me your Dockerfile pls

Comment: FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Andreas Lüdeke
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget

RUN set -ex \
 && buildDeps=' \
  ruby \
 ' \
 && apt-get update \
 && curl -fSL -o ruby.tar.gz "http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p481.tar.gz" \
&& tar -xvzf ruby-2.0.0-p481.tar.gz
&& rm ruby-2.0.0-p481.tar.gz
 && cd ruby-2.0.0-p481/                                                     
&& ./configure --prefix=/usr/local  
 && make
&& make install 
&& apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps \
&& gem update --system 2.4.5 \
&& rm -r /usr/src/ruby
RUN gem install calabash-android

Comment: I don't know whether it is correct or not. Since I am new to this just tried to copy and edit and example. I have followed this one https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/c88f3a67da720bfa9fb1717960d90fd5db11c757/2.3/Dockerfile